# How to fill a ComboBox from SQL Server using Windows Forms in vb? Cannot bind to the new display member. Parameter name: new DisplayMember

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I am having trouble filling a ComboBox in Visual Basic from a database on SQL Server, and at the time I debug my program in the watch I see that the value I put on DisplayMember goes kind of missing, and the value I use in ValueMember appears on the DisplayMember , it also marks an exception on the ValueMember that says: Cannot bind to the new display member. Parameter name: new DisplayMember.
I have the following code while loading the form:

```
 Private Sub Form9_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    
    Dim conexion As New EnlaceBD
    Dim tabla As New DataSet

    tabla = conexion.SetFrecuencias()

    ComboBox1.DataSource = tabla
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Id"

End Sub
```

In another .vb i have the following function:

```
Public Function SetFrecuencias() As DataSet
        Dim Qry As String
        Dim data As New DataSet
        
    Try
        conectar()

        Qry = "sp_Frecuencias"
        comandosql = New SqlCommand(Qry, conexion)
        comandosql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim parametro1 As SqlParameter = comandosql.Parameters.Add("@Opc", SqlDbType.Char, 1)
        parametro1.Value = "X"

        adaptador.SelectCommand = comandosql
        adaptador.Fill(data)
        
    Catch ex As SqlException

    Finally
        desconectar()
    End Try
    Return data

End Function
```

And in SQL i have the Creation of my table and the StoredProcedure:

```
 --TABLE
 IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'Frecuencia' AND type ='U')
    BEGIN 
        DROP TABLE Frecuencia
    END
    CREATE TABLE Frecuencia (
        IdFrecuencia        int identity,
        Nombre              varchar(30),
        Dias                int,
        CONSTRAINT PK_Frecuencia PRIMARY KEY(IdFrecuencia),
    )
--SP
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'sp_Frecuencias' AND type ='P')
BEGIN 
    DROP PROCEDURE sp_Frecuencias
END 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Frecuencias(
    @Opc            char(1),
    @Id             int,
    @Nombre         varchar(30),
    @Dias           int
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF @Opc = 'X'   --SELECT ALL --
        BEGIN
            SELECT IdFrecuencia 'Id', Nombre 'Nombre', Dias 'Dias'
            FROM Frecuencia
        END
END
```

Sorry if the names in spanish are confusing, Nombre means Name, Dias means Days, Frecuencia or Frecuencias is Frecuency, Conexion is Connection, Tabla is Table, Parametro means Parameter and Adaptador is Adapter.

Here´s an image of the exception and the watch:
[Exception and Watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjHEy.png)

Comment: You are missing values for the other parameters. If you want them to have a default, then set one: `@Id int = NULL, @Nombre  varchar(30) = 'something'` Aside: please put connection, command and adapter in `Using` blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure seems to have extra parameters declared that are not used. I am not sure of the format presented. It may need to be tweaked.

```
If EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'sp_Frecuencias' AND type ='P')
BEGIN
            DROP PROCEDURE sp_Frecuencias
End
            GO
            CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Frecuencias(
                @Opc            char(1),
                )
AS
BEGIN
            If @Opc = 'X'   --SELECT ALL --
        BEGIN
                Select Case IdFrecuencia 'Id', Nombre 'Nombre', Dias 'Dias'
                From Frecuencia
        End
End
```

I changed the `DataSet` to a `DataTable`. I think this was your main problem. The `DataSet` does not have fields `Nombre` or `ID`. DataSets hold DataTables among other things. You do not need a `New DataTable` because a New one would just be overwritten by the one returned by `SetFrecuencias`. As I recall the `DataSource` property comes after the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.

```
Private Sub Form9_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim conexion As New EnlaceBD
    Dim tabla = conexion.SetFrecuencias()
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Id"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = tabla
End Sub
```

The data access code uses a `Using...End Using` block which ensure that the connection and command are closed and disposed. Database objects should be local to the method where they are used. You are only dealing with a single table so you do not need a `DataSet`. The `DataAdapter` is also not needed.

Do not write empty `Catch` blocks. That will just swallow errors.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Public Function SetFrecuencias() As DataTable
    Dim data As New DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                comandosql As New SqlCommand("sp_Frecuencias", con)
        comandosql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        comandosql.Parameters.Add(" @Opc", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = "X"c
        con.Open()
        data.Load(comandosql.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return data
End Function
```

**EDIT** as per comments by @Charlieface

```
Public Function SetFrecuencias() As DataTable
    Using data As New DataTable
        Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            comandosql As New SqlCommand("sp_Frecuencias", con)
            comandosql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            comandosql.Parameters.Add(" @Opc", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = "X"c
            con.Open()
            Using reader = comandosql.ExecuteReader
                data.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return data
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: I removed the extra parameters on SQL and changed the order of the combobox but I still use my SetFrecuencias() it was throwing another exception, and it worked that way, so I sticked with it, Thanks @mary

Comment: @Charlieface I believe the Load method handles the reader.

Comment: See [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/R/7dbafcd71c803dc0.html) for the source code. It does close it *only if* it has no more results, but it's also not in a `Using` block so it can fail.

Comment: @Charlieface It seems that, drilling down to dbreader, that all .Dispose does it call Close which is done by the Load method..

Comment: Yes, but it's not in a `Using` block, which internally uses a `Try` / `Finally`. So in case of an exception, it won't be disposed. **Please [read up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) on how the `Using` statement works, and what it protects against.**

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I do understand `Using` blocks. I say "Uncle". See my edit to my answer. Thank you. Sorry for being so stubborn but my ex husband was named Charlie. :-)